# In asp.net using c# publishing a website takes more time

Tags: asp.net, publishing

i created a website using c# in asp.net when i am publishing it. Its taking more than 1 hours to publish that particular site.

Comment: How large is the website? And are you publishing it to a server or locally?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to **publish to remote server** via FTP. Now this will surely take time due to network operations.

Try publishing website to local machine first and then upload it using your preferred FTP client.

I also recommend using **Web Deployment Projects**.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Publishing Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t(VS.80).aspx) to see if you do website publishing properly.